# Count NaN from the last row dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | 98 |
| 10 | 53 | NaN |
| 18 | NaN | NaN |

And I need to count the NaN in every column but only if they start from the last row, so in the example the result will be:

number_last_nan(df)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |

Hoy can I achieve this? thanks in advance

Note:

I'm trying something like this

```
df.fillna(method='bfill').isna()
```

and count the trues

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: it`s that ok for you ?

Comment: @AndrésBustamante, bfill will not take into account NaN on the last row. You need to add the condition to check if NaN before you count NaNs

Comment: the NaN type is checked (sorry for that). And if the last row has a null value, it will not fill anything up, leaving only the gaps from the last row. That was the behavior I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Finally, this worked for me!

```
df.fillna(method='bfill').isna().sum()
```

Comment: do you think this will give you 0,2,2 for A, B, C ? both B and C have NaN on the last row. Do you want 2 or 1 for B.

Comment: I want 1 in B, count only if the NaN starts from the last row my friend @JoeFerndz

Comment: if you want 1 for B and 2 for C while excluding NaN for B on last row but including NaN for C on last row, and you are happy with your answer, then I guess you are good to go.